# What's wrong with my random number generator in Fortran 95 please?

Tags: random, fortran, gfortran

This a randon number generator module that I use to compile along with my main program (not listed here)
When I try to compile my random number generator module to see if it works, I get the following message:

> at line 61: call random_seed( put = seed)
>   Error: size of 'put' argument of 'random_seed' intrinsic too small <4/12>

What does it mean?  How can I fix it?

```
module random_angle
 contains
 0
    integer Function random_integer (N)         ! return a random integer between 1 and N
        integer, intent(in) :: N
        real*8 :: x

        call random_number(x)
        random_integer = floor(real(N)*x)+1

    end function random_integer

    Real*8 Function gasdev()           !  ch7.pg.280:gaussian distribution function using ran1 as random # generator

        implicit none
!       integer, intent(inout) :: idum
        integer, save::iset
        real*8:: fac,rsq,v1,v2
        real*8, dimension(2) :: x
        real*8, save :: gset

!       if (idum.lt.0) iset=0
        if (iset.eq.0) then
          rsq = 0.0
          do while (rsq > 1.0.or.rsq==0)  
            call random_number(x)
            v1=2.*x(1)-1
            v2=2.*x(2)-1
            rsq=v1**2+v2**2
!    print *, v1, v2,rsq
          end do    

          fac=sqrt(-2.*log(rsq)/rsq)
          gset=v1*fac
          gasdev=v2*fac
          iset=1
        else
            gasdev=gset
            iset=0
        endif

        return

    end Function gasdev

    real*8 function NormalRandom (average, stddev)
        implicit none
        real*8, intent(in):: average, stddev
        NormalRandom = average + stddev*gasdev()

    end function NormalRandom

    subroutine setSEED (seed)
        implicit none

        real*8:: x
        integer, dimension(4), intent(inout):: seed
        if (seed(1) == 0.0) &
            seed = floor(1000*secnds(0.0)) +(/0, 37, 74, 111 /)  
        call random_seed( put=seed)

    end subroutine setSEED

end module random_angle
```

Comment: There is also a nice example of how to use `random_seed` in the gfortran's manual https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html#RANDOM_005fSEED

Answer (score 8):

When the compiler says

> Error: size of 'put' argument of 'random_seed' intrinsic too small <4/12>

it means that the size of your variable `seed` is too small.

In this case you have `seed` of size 4 (and I guess the compiler must be expecting (at least) 12).

The size of the array must be of a certain size which depends on the compiler.  You can determine, portably, the required size by a call to `random_seed` with another argument

```
integer seed_size
integer, allocatable :: seed(:)

call random_seed(size=seed_size)
allocate(seed(seed_size))
seed = ...
call random_seed(put=seed)
```

As Vladimir F points out in a comment, the gfortran document itself [has an example](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html#RANDOM_005fSEED) of this approach.

If you don't care about portable, you could just use an array of size 12 with your choice of values.

---

As more advanced reading, I'll say another thing.  The example I gave above really wasn't very comparable to your code.  That is, you say that the input to the seed setting subroutine is guaranteed to be at least of size 4 and it may, or may not, contain values you want to use as seed.

As I noted above, you could change that to 12, but that isn't portable.  If you want to be portable things get more awkward.

```
integer, dimension(4), intent(inout):: seed
```

has as dummy argument an explicit shape array of size 4.  The actual argument in the main program is an array at least that size.  However, this size is a *specification expression* and, alas, `call random_seed(size=seed_size)` doesn't give us something we can use in a specification expression.

Perhaps something like

```
subroutine setSEED (seed)
  integer, allocatable, intent(inout) :: seed(:)
  integer seed_size

  ! Determine the correct size for the seed
  call random_seed(size=seed_size)

  ! If our seed isn't set, or is too small, kill it.
  if (ALLOCATED(seed)) then
    if (SIZE(seed)<seed_size.or.seed(LBOUND(seed,1))==0.) deallocate(seed)
  end if

  ! If seed isn't allocated (perhaps we killed it because it was too small)
  ! then allocate it to the correct size and initialize it.
  if (.not.ALLOCATED(seed)) then
    allocate(seed(seed_size))
    seed = ...  ! Our fallback seed initialization
  end if

  ! Finally, put the seed.  Using one we set, or the one originally given.
  call random_seed(put=seed)

end subroutine
```

This, of course, requires that the actual argument be `allocatable`, but if you're handling portable seed setting that's a good thing.